# release Vs free - why won’t the ARC version of an iOS audio app exit gracefully?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, automatic-ref-counting

I’m revising an early audio app. When I converted it to ARC I discovered the old code to `release` timer, audio session and deviceMotion is now deprecated. Xcode suggests replacing `release` with `free` but I’m having trouble making the audio session release properly.

---

**EDIT** I believe this question has finally been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46294241/2348597).

---

Here is my code

```
- (void)fromEscButton:(UIButton*)button
{
    [self stopClock];
    [self exitGracefully];
    [self goToGlobal];
}

- (void)stopClock
{
    [_synthLock lock];
    [_synth stopAllNotes];
    [_player stop];
    [motionListener stopMotionListener];
    [_synthLock unlock];
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}

-(void)exitGracefully
{
    free((__bridge void *)(lastEventChangeTime));   //  [lastEventChangeTime release];
    free((__bridge void *)(timer));                 //  [timer release];
    free((__bridge void *)(motionListener));        //  [motionListener release];
    free((__bridge void *)(player));                //  [player release];
    free((__bridge void *)(_synth));                //  [synth release];
    free((__bridge void *)(_synthLock));            //  [synthLock release];
}

- (void)goToGlobal
{
    MultiviewAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate displayView:DISPLAY_Help];
}
```

The method `exitGracefully` *(above)* shows the only way I could get `free` to compile. I don’t fully understand `(__bridge void *)` so I strongly suspect it might be wrong.

When I hit the escape button, the clock and sound stop immediately but the app lingers with buffers running and eventually crashes

```
2017-08-18 08:51:30.015004+1000 SatGam2[4846:577981] [aqme] 254: AQDefaultDevice (173): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0
2017-08-18 08:51:32.023461+1000 SatGam2[4846:577981] [aqme] 254: AQDefaultDevice (173): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0
2017-08-18 08:51:34.031960+1000 SatGam2[4846:577981] [aqme] 254: AQDefaultDevice (173): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0
2017-08-18 08:51:35.474 SatGam2[4846:576397] Esc button                  (2)

(lldb) bt
SatGam2 was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
* thread #9, name = 'com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xb000000c)
frame #0: 0x0318c4b6 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 14
  * frame #1: 0x000f9452 SatGam2`__39-[PlayViewController startAudioSession]_block_invoke((null)=0x78f3b6b0, buffer=<unavailable>, audioFormat=AudioStreamBasicDescription @ 0xb0a25ab8) at PlayViewController.m:347 [opt]
frame #2: 0x000f7d87 SatGam2`PlayCallback(inUserData=0x7ab30970, inAudioQueue=<unavailable>, inBuffer=<unavailable>) at AudioBufferPlayer.m:30 [opt]
```

The message in frame #2 `inAudioQueue=<unavailable>, inBuffer=<unavailable>` suggests that the audio session eventually found synth and player have already stopped.

---

EDITS

1. I also commented out the method `exitGracefully` allowing ARC to manage release on its own. However the symptoms continue until it eventually crashed with a different message

   ```
   frame #2: 0x000d9d90 SatGam2`-[PlayViewController .cxx_destruct](self=0x7e249000, _cmd=".cxx_destruct") at PlayViewController.m:20 [opt]
   ```

`PlayViewController` mentioned in the Xcode log is the `ViewController` that was running just before the crash. The simulator shows that the app has switched to a new ViewController *(the new tenant complaining about rubbish left by the previous tenant ?)*

2. I also set the pointers to `nil` (as suggested by Marcio). It crashed the same way but again with a different message

   ```
   frame #2: 0x000000010c6c6e6d SatGam2`__39-[PlayViewController startAudioSession]_block_invoke((null)=<unavailable>, buffer=0x00006000002e1500, audioFormat=AudioStreamBasicDescription @ 0x000070000c31e920) at PlayViewController.m:353 [opt]
   ```

The question might now be: can the message - `[PlayViewController startAudioSession]_block_invoke((null)=<unavailable>` - help to explain why ARC cannot handle this condition ?

---

Can anyone explain the latest crash and what to do so the audio player will exit gracefully ?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: If you have something you were formerly calling `release` on explicitly, then passing it to `free()` is 100% not the right thing to do. Just let ARC take care of the release.

Comment: Josh, that was a good lead. When I tried letting ARC take care of it the symptoms change. See my edit.

Comment: when do you call exitGracefully()?.. why dont you just override dealloc()?